# Iterating over a HashMap, two ways: iterating with entry set & iterating with enumeration

Tags: java, hash, dictionary, iterator, key

Are HashMaps supposed to be iterated in these two ways or is enumeration considered wrong? I made a simple iterator program with two iterator functions:

```
import java.util.*;

public class HashMapIterators
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        HashMap<String, Integer> hMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

        hMap.put("abc", 10);
        hMap.put("pqr", 20);
        hMap.put("asd", 30);
        hMap.put("xyz", 40);

        iteratorEnumeration(hMap);
        iteratorEntrySet(hMap);
    }

    public static void iteratorEnumeration(HashMap hMap)
    {
        System.out.println("iteratorEnumeration");

        Iterator it = hMap.keySet().iterator();
        Enumeration em = hMap.elements();               // doesn't work
        Enumeration em = new IteratorEnumeration(it);   // doesn't work

//      while(em.hasMoreElements())
        {
        }
    }

    public static void iteratorEntrySet(HashMap hMap)
    {
        System.out.println("iteratorEntrySet");

        Iterator it = hMap.entrySet().iterator();

        while(it.hasNext())
        {
            Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry)it.next();
            System.out.println("Key: [" + me.getKey() + "], Value: [" + me.getValue() + "]");
        }
    }
}
```

The iteratorEnumeration function does not work, I guess these methods (like elements()) is applicable on HashTable's only. Correct me if i'm wrong, I don't know when is it appropriate to use what function. So, my main question is - should we iterate over a HashMap by setting a iterator over the entrySet method (please see my iteratorEntrySet function), is this the only right way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of generics, learn 'em &love 'em

second the keySet also has a `iterator()` method that iterates over all keys (the `Enumeration` class is deprecated)

I find the `entrySet` better when I also need the value on each key so I can avoid the cost of the search (which depending on the map can go to `O(n)`)

the iteration code comes down to:

```
for(Map.Entry<KeyClass,ValueClass> e:hMap){
    KeyClass key = e.getKey();
    ValueClass value = e.getValue();
    //...
}
```

if I just need the keys I'll use the keySet as to avoid the extra bloat of `Map.entry<keyClass,ValueClass>` in the for type

Comment: Awesome. So, Enumeration is deprecated & should not be used. Got it.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this would be to use the new [Enhanced `for` Loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) (Foreach), along with generics like so:

```
static <K, V> void iterateForEach(Map<K, V> map)
{
    for(Map.Entry<K, V> entry : map.entrySet())
    {
        System.out.println("Key: [" + entry.getKey() + "], Value: [" + entry.getValue() + "]");
    }
}
```

Comment: my question is whether iterating with entrySet is the only *RIGHT* way to do it, is iterating with enumerations correct, & if it is, how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Is the way you interact with the Map?  If so, you might be using they wrong data structure.

Any way, the problem with your iteratorEnumeration method is once you get the key iterator, you should iterate over it, getting the value from the map each time.  You dont need to call 
`hMap.elements();`

Comment: That was one of the way I was trying to access it. I'll remove that, why does: Enumeration em = new IteratorEnumeration(it); not work??